# device orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.3

I dont know why the device orientation doesn't work.

In the project properties:

[image]

In my code I have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || 
   (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
   (interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

I probe it in my iphone and doesn't change.

Is something missing?

Thank you in advance

Edited (info.plist)

[image]

Comment: Supported interface orientations add in info.plist

Comment: Do you have the orientation lock enabled on your device?

Comment: No, it isn't locked, I also tried with the iphone emulator in xcode

Comment: do you init the view controller in code with your custom initializer? Did you override `-initWithNibName:bundle:`? Is your view controller a child view controller embedded in parent view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Open your `info.plist` file in `XCode` and add a line - `Supported interface orientation` of type array.

Hit the plus button next to it and list all orientations you want to use.
You can set different settings for `iPhone` and `iPad`.

Comment: This is done automatically when you selected the supported orientations as shown in the image above.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
   (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)||
   (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
{
    return YES;
}

return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where in your code is `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` implemented?  It should be a method of each and every subclass of `UIViewController`.

Try making sure that it's working by putting a log statement or breakpoint in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.  If it's not being called, a view controller somewhere else is deciding your valid orientations for you.

Comment: I tried what you said with NSLog, the method is called, but it doesn't change